# Problem running .bat file on Windows due to "input line is too long"

Tags: java, windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm using Windows and have a batch file (contents attached below) where I'm building up a classpath before trying to run a Java class.  Unfortunately the classpath is fairly big and the file ends up being ~14kb.  When I run it I'm getting an 'input line too long' error.  I have read elsewhere that the max. size for an env variable is 8kb, but it looks unlikely that I'll be able to reduce the size of my classpath to fit that.  Is there anything else I can do to get this to run?

thanks,
Nick

```
echo off
subst z: C:\Users\ned24\.m2\repository
set CLASSPATH=c:\workspace-eclipse\lensfield-pom\lensfield-build\target\classes;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\wwmm\atom-archiver\0.1\atom-archiver-0.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.9\freemarker-2.3.9.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\log4j\log4j\1.2.13\log4j-1.2.13.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\xom\xom\1.1\xom-1.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.2\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\xerces\xercesImpl\2.6.2\xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\jaxen\jaxen\1.1-beta-8\jaxen-1.1-beta-8.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\jdom\jdom\1.0\jdom-1.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\cdk\cdk-pure\1.2.1\cdk-pure-1.2.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\cml\cifxml\1.4-SNAPSHOT\cifxml-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\jgrapht\jgrapht\0.6.0\jgrapht-0.6.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\cml\jumbo-converters\0.2-SNAPSHOT\jumbo-converters-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\cml\jumbo\5.5.1-SNAPSHOT\jumbo-5.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\cml\cmlxom\2.5.1-SNAPSHOT\cmlxom-2.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\junit\junit\3.8\junit-3.8.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\commons\commons-cli\2.0-SNAPSHOT\commons-cli-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\cml\jumbo-units\0.2-SNAPSHOT\jumbo-units-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\lensfield\lensfield-share\0.1-SNAPSHOT\lensfield-share-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-embedder\3.0-alpha-2\maven-embedder-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-core\3.0-alpha-2\maven-core-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-lifecycle\3.0-alpha-2\maven-lifecycle-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\1.5.6\plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-reporting-api\3.0-alpha-2\maven-reporting-api-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\doxia\doxia-sink-api\1.0-alpha-9\doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-9.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-model\3.0-alpha-2\maven-model-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-compat\3.0-alpha-2\maven-compat-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-container-default\1.0-beta-3.0.5\plexus-container-default-1.0-beta-3.0.5.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-classworlds\1.3\plexus-classworlds-1.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\xbean\xbean-reflect\3.4\xbean-reflect-3.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\commons-logging\commons-logging-api\1.1\commons-logging-api-1.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\google\code\google-collections\google-collect\snapshot-20080530\google-collect-snapshot-20080530.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-component-annotations\1.0-beta-3.0.5\plexus-component-annotations-1.0-beta-3.0.5.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-provider-api\1.0-beta-4\wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-plugin-api\3.0-alpha-2\maven-plugin-api-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-project\3.0-alpha-2\maven-project-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-interpolation\1.1\plexus-interpolation-1.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\codehaus\woodstox\wstx-asl\3.2.6\wstx-asl-3.2.6.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\stax\stax-api\1.0\stax-api-1.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\sonatype\spice\model-builder\1.3\model-builder-1.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-project-builder\3.0-alpha-2\maven-project-builder-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.0\commons-cli-1.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-interactivity-api\1.0-alpha-6\plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-plugin-manager\1.0-alpha-1\plexus-plugin-manager-1.0-alpha-1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-plexus\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-plexus-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-repo-remote-m2\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-repo-remote-m2-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-repo-api\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-repo-api-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-artifact\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-artifact-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-lang\1.1\plexus-lang-1.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-transport-api\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-transport-api-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-crypto-api\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-crypto-api-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-logging\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-logging-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-external\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-external-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-event\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-event-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-md-shared\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-md-shared-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-util\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-util-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-crypto-basic\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-crypto-basic-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15\140\bcprov-jdk15-140.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\bouncycastle\bcpg-jdk15\140\bcpg-jdk15-140.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-transport-http\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-transport-http-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-client\6.1.12\jetty-client-6.1.12.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-sslengine\6.1.12\jetty-sslengine-6.1.12.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty\6.1.12\jetty-6.1.12.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.1.12\jetty-util-6.1.12.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\mortbay\jetty\servlet-api-2.5\6.1.12\servlet-api-2.5-6.1.12.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-repo-local-m2\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-repo-local-m2-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-repo-virtual\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-repo-virtual-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-repo-cache-fs\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-repo-cache-fs-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\mercury\mercury-md-sat\1.0.0-alpha-2\mercury-md-sat-1.0.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\sat4j\org.sat4j.core\2.0.4\org.sat4j.core-2.0.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\sat4j\org.sat4j.pb\2.0.4\org.sat4j.pb-2.0.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\slf4j\slf4j-jdk14\1.5.3\slf4j-jdk14-1.5.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.5.0\slf4j-api-1.5.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-mercury\3.0-alpha-2\maven-mercury-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-toolchain\3.0-alpha-2\maven-toolchain-3.0-alpha-2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-http-lightweight\1.0-beta-4\wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-http-shared\1.0-beta-4\wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\nekohtml\xercesMinimal\1.9.6.2\xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.6.2\nekohtml-1.9.6.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-ssh\1.0-beta-4\wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\jcraft\jsch\0.1.38\jsch-0.1.38.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-ssh-common\1.0-beta-4\wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-ssh-external\1.0-beta-4\wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-file\1.0-beta-4\wagon-file-1.0-beta-4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-api\2.2.4\sesame-repository-api-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-query\2.2.4\sesame-query-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-model\2.2.4\sesame-model-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-collections\2.3\aduna-commons-collections-2.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-concurrent\2.2\aduna-commons-concurrent-2.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-iteration\2.3\aduna-commons-iteration-2.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-i18n\1.0\aduna-commons-i18n-1.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-api\2.2.4\sesame-rio-api-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-lang\2.3\aduna-commons-lang-2.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-net\2.2\aduna-commons-net-2.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-text\2.2\aduna-commons-text-2.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-io\2.4\aduna-commons-io-2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryresultio-api\2.2.4\sesame-queryresultio-api-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryparser-sparql\2.2.4\sesame-queryparser-sparql-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryparser-api\2.2.4\sesame-queryparser-api-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryalgebra-model\2.2.4\sesame-queryalgebra-model-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-sail\2.2.4\sesame-repository-sail-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-api\2.2.4\sesame-sail-api-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-nativerdf\2.2.4\sesame-sail-nativerdf-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-inferencer\2.2.4\sesame-sail-inferencer-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryparser-serql\2.2.4\sesame-queryparser-serql-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryalgebra-evaluation\2.2.4\sesame-queryalgebra-evaluation-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryresultio-sparqlxml\2.2.4\sesame-queryresultio-sparqlxml-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\info\aduna\commons\aduna-commons-xml\2.2\aduna-commons-xml-2.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-rdfxml\2.2.4\sesame-rio-rdfxml-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-turtle\2.2.4\sesame-rio-turtle-2.2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\net\sourceforge\jena\jena\2.4\jena-2.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\antlr\antlr\2.7.5\antlr-2.7.5.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\net\sourceforge\jena\arq\1.4\arq-1.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\net\sourceforge\jena\iri\1.0\iri-1.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1\commons-logging-1.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\logkit\logkit\1.0.1\logkit-1.0.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\avalon-framework\avalon-framework\4.1.3\avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.3\servlet-api-2.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\concurrent\concurrent\1.3.4\concurrent-1.3.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\icu4j\icu4j\3.4\icu4j-3.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\json\json\1.0\json-1.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\woodstox\wstx-asl\2.8\wstx-asl-2.8.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\owlapi\owlapi\2.2.0\owlapi-2.2.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.4.2\slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\clojure\clojure-lang\1.1.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT\clojure-lang-1.1.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\clojure\clojure-contrib\1.0-SNAPSHOT\clojure-contrib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\wwmm\pub-crawler\0.1\pub-crawler-0.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.2\commons-codec-1.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\dspace\foresite\SNAPSHOT\foresite-SNAPSHOT.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\hp\hpl\jena\jena\2.5.5\jena-2.5.5.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\hp\hpl\jena\arq\2.2\arq-2.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\apache\lucene\lucene-core\2.2.0\lucene-core-2.2.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\hp\hpl\jena\arq-extra\2.2\arq-extra-2.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\hp\hpl\jena\jenatest\2.5.5\jenatest-2.5.5.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\hp\hpl\jena\iri\0.5\iri-0.5.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\3.4.4\icu4j-3.4.4.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\hp\hpl\jena\concurrent-jena\1.3.2\concurrent-jena-1.3.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\com\hp\hpl\jena\json-jena\1.0\json-jena-1.0.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\rome\rome\0.9\rome-0.9.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\org\ccil\cowan\tagsoup\tagsoup\1.0.1\tagsoup-1.0.1.jar;%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=z:\javax\vecmath\1.2\vecmath-1.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%

java clojure.main "%LENSFIELD_HOME%\lensfield-build\src\main\clj\lensfield\cli.clj" %*
```

Comment: It looks like the z drive is the root of a Maven repository. Is there a reason why you aren't using ant+Ivy or Maven to run this or to package the dependencies into a "lib" directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using Java 6, you can use a wildcard in the classpath, for example:

```
java -cp libs/* com.mypackage.MyProgram
```

See [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) (scroll down to "Understanding class path wildcards") for more details.

Note: This doesn't work on older versions of Java.

Comment: This is new to me and I've been using 6 for 18 months!  Good to know.

Comment: how would you get Ant to retrieve the string "libs/*" from the <path>..</path> object ?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size for an environment variable is around 32760 characters. However, the maximum size for a single command line in `cmd` (and therefore in batch files) is 8190 characters.

Since you're building a very long `CLASSPATH` variable here you encounter that limitation, even though the environment variable in question can still be much longer. Delayed expansion probably won't help here since it still results in a unwieldy long command line.

Currently I see two options:

- Use VBScript instead of a batch file. I guess<sup>1</sup> that it supports lines longer than that. Also you are not forced to have the entire classpath written out in a single line of code; it can easily be in a string.
- Use `setx`, included with Windows Vista or later, or in the Windows Resource kit before that. `setx` allows you to read from a file, but it also writes directly to the registry, so it's essentially equivalent to setting the classpath in your user's environment (instead of only for a single process).

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm nowhere sure but it doesn't inherit the legacy codebase of `cmd` so it might be a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to refactor by defining more drive letters, i.e. if you had W: to point at "z:\org\apache\maven\" that ought to cut out a few characters. Repeat that a couple of times, and you might get low enough for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the **`subst`** command you could try to create short symbolic links to all the directories where your JARs reside. Use the free [**`junction`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) tool from the Windows Sysinternals Suite to achieve this.

> [...]
>
> **Using Junction**
>
> Use junction to list junctions:
>
> Usage: [-s]
>
> -s    Recurse subdirectories
>
> Examples:
>
> To determine if a file is a junction,
>   specify the file name:
>
> `junction c:\test`
>
> To list junctions beneath a directory,
>   include the –s switch:
>
> `junction -s c:\`
>
> To create a junction c:\Program-Files
>   for "c:\Program Files":
>
> `C:\>md Program-Files`
>
> `C:\>junction c:\Program-Files "c:\Program Files"`
>
> To delete a junction, use the –d
>   switch:
>
> `junction -d c:\Program-Files`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely au courant on Windows specifics, but given that you're having a command line problem, and not a variable size problem, can't you define variables and use those?  For example:

```
    
    set PLEXHOME=z:\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-component-annotations\1.0-beta-3.0.5\plexus-component-annotations-1.0-beta-3.0.5.jar
    set CLASSPATH=%PLEXHOME%;%CLASSPATH%
    set WAGONHOME=z:\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-provider-api\1.0-beta-4\wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-4.jar
    set CLASSPATH=%WAGONHOME%;%CLASSPATH%
    set MAVENAPIHOME=z:\org\apache\maven\maven-plugin-api\3.0-alpha-2\maven-plugin-api-3.0-alpha-2.jar
    set CLASSPATH=%MAVENAPIHOME%;%CLASSPATH%
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you hunting for the java class path? If you know where the class is, then just call that class by the direct path name, not its file name.

Answer (score 0):

Do any of those jars care where they live? Could you just have the batch file copy them all into a localjar directory, and then you could just list them?

You could use `xcopy /d/y`, which only copies if the file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you are running vista and java 6 is to make a directory with symbolic links using the [MKLINK](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/) command so that all the jars appear in one directory, and then use the java 6 ability to reference all of the jars with a *.jar.

I think the other answers pretty much exhaust the windows options, but another option is to make a wrapper jar that invokes the clojure.main and puts all of these jars in its classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first set CLASSPATH=....;%CLASSPATH% just eliminate the %CLASSPATH% at the end. The error isn't descriptive, but is because %CLASSPATH% has not value.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was no solution worked to the issue other than somehow making the classpath shorter by moving the jar files into a folder like "C:\jars".